# Redirect To App issue for Google Authentication in Ios 7 only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-app-engine, redirect

I Implemented the Login With Google in my app.

But when the User `press Accept` the Safari will not redirect to my app in ios 7. But when I try to run in ios 6/6.1, it works fine.

**My code is as follow**

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.clientID = kClientID;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn authenticate];
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using Google+ iOS SDK version 1.4.1, in my app and It's working in both iOS.